# Как можно отследить событие проведения нажатой мышкой по обьектам на веб странице

Tags: html, javascript, css

Я хочу (несмейтесь) попытаться сделать игру Fruit Ninja для веб на html/css/javascript, как можно отследить проведение нажатой мышкой (как на тачскрине пальцем) по обьекту (желательно пример кода например alert при проведении над div'ом нажатой кнопкой)

Comment: А что mousemove не устраивает?

Comment: не ведь есле в Warcraft например наведёш мышкой а боец уже сам выберется играть ведь не в кайф!?

Comment: А что mousemove не устраивает?// В игре есть бомбы. Спастись от них можно подняв ненадолго палец от экрана, не тратя времени на "объезд". Времени экономится уйма.

Comment: Я в игру не играл до этого времени. А в вопросе я подразумевал, что можно отслеживать флаг нажатия мыши, который можно устанавливать при mousedown и снимать при mouseup. Но ИМХО если возникают затруднения в таких вещах, то вряд ли, получится осуществить задуманное, однако попробовать всегда можно ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите любой пример [drag and drop интерфейса](http://javascript.ru/ui/draganddrop), когда зажимается кнопка, происходит событие onmousedown, потом идет обработка с помощью события onmousemove и когда перетаскиваемый объект входит в нужную область (сравниваются координаты нужных объектов), то вызывается любая функция, хоть алерт.

Answer (score 0):

Делаете поле div на нем отрисовываете объекты. И на само поле вещаете перехватчики событий: onmousedown, onmousemove, onmouseup...

Если при onmousemove мышка прошлась по объекту, то вызываете функцию уничтожения объекта событием onmouseover.

```
<div id="field">
    <div id="im_fruit"></div>
</div>

<script>
  $("#field").mousedown(function(){
    $("#im_fruit").bind("mouseover", fimction(){
        alert("Im killed!!");
     });
  }).mouseup(function(){
     $("#im_fruit").unbind("mouseover");
  });
</script>
```

Это с использование JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Нажатие кнопки можно отследить по event.button
подробности

Answer (score 0):

повесь на боди обработчик что бы узнавать на каком элементе ты находишся, а для того что бы узнать зажата кнопка или нет используй какой то флаг, как только кнопка отпущена флаг == false.